# Beta App Does Not Launch Or Create Shortcut

Tags: android, google-play, manifest, launch

I just published my app to the Play Store as a beta. I received the download link and created the google group for beta testers...I am able to install the app using the link but a shortcut is not created for the app nor does the app launch.  I looked through the application manager and was able to find my app but it is obvious my app never ran.  I tried uninstalling/reinstalling but no luck....

Tried on a Samsung Galaxy 3 and a Droid Razr M

I followed the Google Checklist for launch as well as I could and believe I signed and exported the app properly because I created a keystore password, alias, saved the .apk to a location and uploaded the .apk to my developer console

Also, I believe I no longer need to get a release key for Google Maps API because I can use the debug key due to the update.....Let me know if I am wrong

Note that the app has been running fine when debugging through eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alpha.boozl"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission
    android:name="com.alpha.boozl.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.alpha.boozl.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

    <!-- <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> -->

    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.Main"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- I changed this part for the Search activity instead of the normal Search_Page -->

    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.RandomAlc"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.RANDOM" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.Search"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.DealPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.DEALPAGE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.StorePage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.STOREPAGE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.Map"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.MAP" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.TapDealTest"
        android:label="TapDeal"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.TAPDEALTEST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.StoreSearch"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.STORESEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.alpha.boozl.MainCall"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.alpha.boozl.MAINCALL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Left Blank" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent filter on `com.alpha.boozl.Main` is incorrect.

It should be

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You have `com.alpha.boozl.MAIN` instead of the correct action `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

I'm not sure if you are using them or not, but you don't have to define an Intent Filter on each `Activity` unless you explicitly handle `Intents` inside them. Android automatically handles the intent needed when calling `startActivity()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm